# For loop to compare a .csv file with Latitudes and longitudes to a Dataclass

Tags: python, csv, geolocation

Just as the title implies and due to my lack of experience :( I'm actually facing a problem on how to actually tackle this problem, which is the following:

***1.-*** I have a function (built into a custom python library) which returns a Dataclass after you pass it 2 parameters, which are latitude and longitude (example below the numbered bullets)

***2.-*** I also have a .csv file with 2 values, which are Latitude and Longitude.

***3.-*** I need to actually build some kind of for loop to actually travel through the entire .csv file and pass them sequentially to the aforementioned function in order to get all the responses/dataclasses being shown either through Terminal or if possible passed into a .txt file or something like that (whichever works tbh).

The actual function is called like this:

```
from apps.geo.address_list.servlet import retrieve retrieve_addresses_latlng

response = retrieve_addresses_latlng(33.593801,-112.230910)   ##here you simply pass it the lat,lng
```

which gives us a Dataclass that looks like this:

```
AddressData(country_code='US', administrative_area_level_1='US', county='San Diego County', postal_code='92056', 579068)
```

With this I need to actually be able to pass every lat,lng from the .csv file that I mentioned to the actual function in a "sequential" way to actually trigger the function as many times as needed and being able to see the output for all of them either through console or .txt file :')

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated since I'm really really new at programming but I'm eager to learn more of this amazing world :D

Best regards and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each set of coordinates is on a separate line of your CSV file, you could do something like this:

```
from apps.geo.address_list.servlet import retrieve_addresses_latlng

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lat, lng = line.split(',')
        data = retrieve_address_latlng(lat, lng)
        print(data)
```

This is very simple way of reading data from a file, line by line. You could use a CSV parsing library instead, but for this trivial example, you'll learn more manipulating the data manually.

The 'sequential' part of this solution is the `for` loop, which iterates through each set of coordinates (one per line) provided by `f.readlines()`.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Holvey !
Thanks for your help here!! just one thing is missing though :(
giving that the response from the retrieve_address_latlng is a Dataclass when you try to print it like print(data) I'm getting None, None....

Any idea or workaround on how to actually print a dataclass several times using the same for loop :O?

Comment: You may need to experiment with a single instance of `Dataclass` to make sure it's being created properly. None, None suggests that the properties aren't being set properly (assuming the class knows how to format itself as a string for printing)